# stripe tired graduate pricing api doesn't return amount

Tags: stripe-payments

`stripe pricing api` doesn't provide details of `tired -graduate` pricing amounts.

```
::Stripe::Price.retrieve('price_1HMjKfHHVdXnGelT')
```

Here is the respone:

```
<Stripe::Price:0x3fed95f00ab0 id=price_1HMjKfHHVdXnss3> JSON: {
  "id": "price_1HMjKfHHVdXnGelT7fB47cEk",
  "object": "price",
  "active": true,
  "billing_scheme": "tiered",
  "created": 1599004569,
  "currency": "aud",
  "livemode": false,
  "lookup_key": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "nickname": null,
  "product": "prod_HwcZXLTSewzcj1",
  "recurring": {"aggregate_usage":null,"interval":"month","interval_count":1,"trial_period_days":null,"usage_type":"licensed"},
  "tiers_mode": "graduated",
  "transform_quantity": null,
  "type": "recurring",
  "unit_amount": null,
  "unit_amount_decimal": null
}
```

This image is stripe dashboard(Developer console -> Network tab).
`tiers` keys is missing in the above api

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`expanding responses` in stripe [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects)  solved this.

```
Stripe::Price.retrieve({id:'price_1HMjKfHHVdXnGelT', expand: ['tiers']})
```